# Flex: weird question, can't access application property in init event of SWFLoader

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Very weird problem, I am new to AS, but I have to say it's hard to comprehend AS is a modern language:

```
            private function completed():void
            {               
                trace("completed.");                
                var player:Object = (loader.content as SystemManager).application as Object;
                player.playVideo();
                player.setSize(200,300);
            }


    SWFLoader id="loader" horizontalCenter="0" width="100%" height="362" source="http://localhost:8000/testflv1.swf" init="completed()"
```

What I want to do is embed a swf in another parent swf, and call a function from parent to the embedded swf. Then, I use the init event for the SWFLoader to invoke the method. Before doing this I have verified that using the same code in a button click handler, it is fine with:

`var player:Object = (loader.content as SystemManager).application as Object;`

But if in a init event handler, the (loader.content as SystemManager).application is a null.

Whereas, in the document of SWFLoader:

`init
Dispatched when the properties and methods of a loaded SWF file are accessible.`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here because the application property of your included file is not yet initialized.
You can listen to the APPLICATION_COMPLETE event, which will tell you when the application property of your SWF content is completed.

```
        public var loadedSM:SystemManager;

        private function init():void
        {                               
            trace("init.");                            
            loadedSM = SystemManager(loader.content);
            loadedSM.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, callFunc);                
        }

        private function callFunc(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            LoadFileInclude(loadedSM.application).playVideo();
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:SWFLoader id="loader" horizontalCenter="0" width="100%" height="362" source="LoadFileInclude.swf" creationComplete="init()" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it can't work. the Error is: 
<pre>
Property playVideo not found on _testflv1_mx_managers_SystemManager and there is no default value
</pre>

I have the playVideo defined in the swf file embedded:

<pre><code>
   public function playVideo():void
   {
    // Alert.show('playVideo');
    svid.play();
    return;
   }
</code></pre>

Comment: If I catch the event of a button - click the button to invoke the embedded swf's method, it will work with Object way(declare player to be an Object), but not the MovieClip way! That's really weird.

Comment: it still can't work, in the line of: loadedSM = SystemManager(loader.content); the error is: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert _testflv1_mx_managers_SystemManager@6cd3479 to mx.managers.SystemManager.)

Comment: that is odd, it works for me. is it possible for you to paste some simple sources in here which reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  Googling around forever and finally found an answer that led me to the solution buried in this [Old Nabble thread](http://old.nabble.com/Accessing-properties-of-Embedded-Flash-SWFs-from-Flex-3-td20442092.html).

Basically, when the SWF is injected, the MovieClip itself is in a different place, and it's kind of a pain to get it out.  What I did:

MXML:

```
    <mx:SWFLoader
       id="loader"
        source="@Embed(source='/flash/preloader.swf')" />
```

AS:

```
    var mc:MovieClip = Loader(DisplayObjectContainer(swf.content).getChildAt(0)).content 
            as MovieClip;
    if(mc)
    {
        mc.callAFunction();
    }
```